# Marketing Cloud Business Units and Single CRM instance

Tags: marketing-cloud, sfmc-business-unit

I am in the process of helping  a customer with Marketing Cloud setup and they only have one CRM instance. However I am recommending for Multi-Org enabled though they have one CRM instance. My rational is not to do any development(automation, journeys etc) at Parent business unit except Administration(create users, roles etc) and all the development will be done at child business unit which will be connected to the CRM instance.

Do you think it is a best approach in the long term? Would appreciate any input.

Answer (score 1):

This is certainly possible connecting [Multiple Business Units to a Single Org](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_co_multi_org_scenario_examples.htm&type=5).

[image: Multi Org Example]

> In this example, both business units, BU1 and BU2, belong to the same
>   Enterprise 2.0 account. Both business units are connected to the same
>   Sales or Service Cloud Org, ORGA, using connected app authentication.
>   A user, U1, has access to both business units. Because both business
>   units are connected to ORGA, U1 must be connected to the same Sales or
>   Service Cloud user account, UA.
>
> If BU1 and ORGA are disconnected, U1 and UA are disconnected in BU1.
>   U1 remains connected to UA in BU2. BU2 remains connected to ORGA. BU1,
>   ORGA, U1, and UA can reconnect using the multi-org connection rules.

But without knowing how the Parent BU and Child BUs are related (and how many business units), it's difficult to determine the best approach. For example, why do they even have a Parent BU if they're not going to use it and only use it for admin purposes?

Comment: The Parent BU is the default one that comes with any instance and I am not creating it. For now, only one child business unit.

Comment: Sure it can be done. I'd review the considerations such as required custom profile center and user connections.